# How to reduce MS Sql 2008 R2 Log File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had very large data in database(log) after deleting all the records in the database tables but the database size is not reduced , specially Log File(s) Ldf

```
ROWS      56274.125000   55306.625000
LOG       179705.437500  179567.046875
```

how i reduce the size ?

Comment: Shrink the Log file.. After deleting huge amount of data, shrinking the log file is not bad. Just hit google about it..

Answer (score 1):

Is the database in Full Recovery Model? If so, you will need to implement Transaction log backups before you can shrink the log-file size.

If you do not need transaction log backups (in case your full backup is taken often enough that the business is okay with losing the amount of data since the previous backup), you can switch the database to run in Simple recovery model.

You can find out which recovery model a database is in by right-clicking the database, selecting "*Properties*", and then checking the "*Options*" tab.

[image]

You can change the recovery model at that location, too. However, before you do, I highly recommend you to read up on the different [recovery models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server), and the implications of changing them.

When you are ready to change the recovery model, you might want to [read this first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421370/the-transaction-log-for-database-databasename-is-full/13424475#13424475).